# Intel XDK, conflito jquery-1.11.3.min.js e ionic.bundle.js

Tags: php, javascript, intel-xdk

Estou fazendo um `select` simples, pois estou aprendendo a usar o Intel SDK.

Percebi que existe um conflito entre os arquivo:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Usado para fazer a busca no banco de dados e

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

que não faço ideia para que serve, mas se esta lá serve para alguma coisa...rs.

Descobri isso após remover linha por linha. Se eu não coloco o `jquery-1.11.3.min.js`não consigo fazer o select, se coloco esse `ionic.bundle.js`.

O que fazer nessa situação?

Se for necessário esse é meu JS usado para buscar o que preciso.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var operacao = "config";
        $.getJSON("http://meu-site.net/testeConexaoMobileJson.php", {operacao:operacao}, function(json){
            $("#foto").html(json[0].foto);
            $("#nome_da_igreja").html(json[0].nome_da_igreja);
        });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri, basta usar a versão 2 do jQuery.